# Drywalling garage wall - what to do with electrical boxes?

Tags: electrical, drywall

How can I properly drywall an open section of my garage, considering I have a 240V box and want to dismantle old switches and a light fixture to turn it into a junction/splice box? Should I incorporate access panels, and what are the best practices for this project? Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Please see the attached image for reference.

[image: open wall]

Comment: All boxes kept/used must be accessible without tools.  An access door on hinges is okay, but a door/panel screwed onto the wall is not.

Comment: Could I just make them flush with the drywall and screw a cover onto them?

Comment: I'd say the spring-loaded access panels would be OK as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Code requires that any and every junction box (in use) be permanently accessible.

If you're not going to use that light fixture, you can remove the fixture, pull the wire from it, remove the wire from the wall and remove the wire from the box below it, then you can drywall over the box where the light was mounted. Of course, at this point, you may as well remove the box from the wall, too.

If you think there's *ever* a chance you might want to use that box (and you never know), just leave it as is, cut your drywall around it and put a blank cover plate over the box once the drywall is up.

I'm not sure if you're planning on keeping the 2-gang box on the left. If the outlets controlled by the right-hand switch are always on, there's no real need for the switch, just join the wires with a wire nut and replace the cover plate with a blank cover plate (no holes).

The 240v box on the right must also be accessible because there are live wires in the box. The blank cover plate on it now must remain accessible once the drywall is up.

If these boxes are all mounted flush with the edges of the studs, when you put drywall up, they'll be anywhere from 1/4" to 5/8" behind the face of the drywall. You *can* work with them like that, but it'll be a pain in the future and the next person in there (maybe even future you) will curse you for it. Get "mud rings" to match the thickness of your planned drywall and attach them to the boxes. This will move the device mounting points out to be flush with the surface of the drywall and will make everything easier to finish nicely.

Comment: Rather than "mud rings", wouldn't it be better to simply move the boxes themselves out ½"?

Comment: That's a reasonable option too, @RayButterworth. Depends on how the boxes are mounted, though. The plastic boxes I used to use with built in nails are exceedingly difficult to get out of the wall without destroying - a mud ring would be easier. A metal box screwed in to the stud should be very easy to move.

Comment: "*built in nails are exceedingly difficult to get out of the wall without destroying*". Right.  Whenever I install any box, I always use screws. As you almost said: "*the next person in there (maybe even future you) will thank you for it*".

Comment: "I always use screws". Except that the plastic boxes that come from the big box stores already have nails in the mounting wings, and I'm willing to bet that 99.99% of people who install these boxes use the nails instead of pulling the nails and putting screws in (which may well void the UL listing). All the _metal_ boxes I've mounted in the last few months of new construction work have 100% been screwed in. Of course, getting those out will involve destroying drywall, but once I've done that, at least getting the box out will be easier...